# Run a batch file located on another path (other than System32) via psexec

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, remote-access, psexec

I am using psexec to run a batch file located on the remote machine's desktop. I am using the following code:

```
C:\Users\myprofilename\Desktop\PSTools>psexec \\REMORESERVERNAME -u USERNAME -p MYPASSWORD cmd 'C:\Users\NAMEHERE\Desktop\makedir.bat'
```

This command works but it only opens cmd on the remote desktop with the current directory set as `System32` folder.

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>
```

But the important part of my command (running the batch file on the desktop) is ignored.

The method works when I manually change the directory to the desktop and run the batch file, but I want the entire process to be run using once command. The batch file does nothing but create a directory on `C:/`. What am I missing on my `psexec` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
psexec \\REMORESERVERNAME -u USERNAME -p MYPASSWORD cmd "C:\Users\NAMEHERE\Desktop\makedir.bat" -w "C:\Users\NAMEHERE\Desktop"
```

with `-w` you can set a working directory.

Comment: I tried this, but again I only get an open cmd at `C:\windows\system32` and the batch file is not run.

Answer (score 0):

**CMD** requires a switch.  Either `/c` to run command and exit or `/k` to run and stay open. See `cmd /?`.

Comment: Added '/c' to no avail. PsExec is run and I am connected. But the prompt is open at `c:\windows\system32>` and the batch file is not run-